# -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6891460

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Please solve my issue it giving me error as
-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6891460

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.1.190:8080/mwharf/retrive.action?action=consigneeName&startConsgn=";
NSString *url = [urlString stringByAppendingString:txtConsignee.text];

NSData *webData=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];    

NSArray *jsonDict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSMutableArray *tempArray;
NSMutableArray *consigneeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSInteger arrayCount=0;
for (int i=0; i<[jsonDict count]; i++) {              
    consigneeArray =[jsonDict objectAtIndex:i]; 
    NSLog(@"consigneeArray :%@",consigneeArray);
    tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[consigneeArray objectAtIndex:arrayCount]]; 
    [consigneeArray insertObject:tempArray atIndex:arrayCount];
    arrayCount++; 
} 

NSArray *passArray=[NSArray arrayWithObject:consigneeArray];
NSLog(@"passArray :%@",passArray);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this piece of code?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the source JSON data?

Comment: i have added sample of JSON Data source..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:] returns a NSDictionary and not NSArray. So because NSDictionary has no such method objectAtIndex you've got an error. Try this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSMutableArray *tempArray;
NSMutableArray *consigneeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSInteger arrayCount=0;
for(NSString* key in jsonDict) {


    consigneeArray =[jsonDict valueForKey: key]; 
    NSLog(@"consigneeArray :%@",consigneeArray);
    tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[consigneeArray objectAtIndex:arrayCount]]; 
    [consigneeArray insertObject:tempArray atIndex:arrayCount];
    arrayCount++; 
}
```

However return type could also be NSArray or NSString, it depends on your JSON structure. So the best way is to check the return type using

```
 [returnObj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]

 [returnObj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
```

etc.

and parse each return type respectively

Comment: Actually at this point we don't know what the object is, since we don't have the JSON data, but there is a good chance that it is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because you are try to go through the object at specific index using NSString's object. While objectAtIndex supports only NSArray or NSMutableArray.